# Need VBA code to filter with two conditions

Tags: excel, vba

> Closed. This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently
>   accepting answers. Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving.
>   This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question
>   or post a new one.
>
> Closed 14 hours ago by SJR, Erik A, Amit Joshi.
>
> (Private feedback for you)

I am new to VBA code . I have two cells with drop down values (C1) and (C2) . In C1 i have two values ex: A, B . In C2 i have drop down values x,y z. i Have applied filter on both. If i selects A and X is should go and filter the values with A and X similarly for others

i written for one cell not able to combine both cells C1 and C2, is there a way using AND operator. we can achieve it?

```
For Each cel In Range("C2")

    If cel.Value = "A"  Then

ElseIF If cel.Value = "B" Then
```